# Why the number of relation on a set of $3$ element is $512$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

Why the number of relation on a set of $3$ element is $512$?

But I could only see $9$ relations in it. 
I could not understand the formula $2^{2n}-1$

Comment: Which 9 did you find?

Comment: What do you mean by `2^n2-1`? This seems inconsistent with both the answers given. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to this site! If the issue has been resolved, do consider [accepting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) ✔ and upvoting ▲ answers: this signals resolution, prevents the page from being bumped, scores points, and influences the site's search results, cleanup activities, and other behind-the-scenes processes.

Answer (score 3):

View a relation $R$ on a set $A$ as a subset of $A \times A$ in the following way: consider the set $\{(a_1, a_2): a_1 R a_2\}$ to represent the relation $R$. Now $|A \times A| = |A|^2$. So number of subsets of $A \times A$ is $2^{|A \times A|} = 2^{|A|^2}$, which is $2^9 =512$ in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following 2 sets:
$$A=\{1,2,3\}$$
$$B=\{a,b,c\}$$
So, $A\times A=\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\}$
And $A\times B=\{(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(2,a),(2,b),(2,c),(3,a),(3,b),(3,c)\}$

$n(A\times A)=n(A)\times n(A)=3\times 3=9$
$n(A\times B)=n(A)\times n(B)=3\times 3=9$

By definition:

> ***Any subset of $A × B$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$.***
>
> A relation pairs up elements of $A$ with elements in $B$.
> If $a$ from $A$ is paired with $b$ from $B$ in a relation $R$, then we write $(a, b) ∈ R$ or $aRb$.
>
> **Example**: $A = \{1, 2, 3\}, B = \{a, b\}$ then $R = \{(1, a), (3, b)\}$ is a possible relation.

So, the number of possible relations is $2^k$ where $k=n(A)\times n(B)$.
Here, $k=9$ so, the number of possible relations is $2^9=512.$